# Shared libraries error when opening desktop head unit Android Auto (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open the desktop-head-unit executable on Ubuntu and i get this output when trying:

```
$ ./desktop-head-unit
./desktop-head-unit: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got past this issue by running

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0
```

Then I hit another error and passed that with

```
sudo apt-get install libportaudio2
```

Now I am getting this:

```
$ ./desktop-head-unit 
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...failed.
Failed to start Google Automotive Link.
```

I am working on it.

Also it is a good idea to run `./desktop-head-unit --adb 5554` to set the tcpip port.